# Euler representation of rotation matrix and its uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Using  three [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)  we can **represent** any 3-d rotation matrix.
Let's assume that allowable Euler angles must be equal to $i\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ $\,$,  $i=0.. 3$  $\,$ i.e.
 $\alpha = \{0,\dfrac{\pi}{2},{\pi}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ (the same effect as in case of $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ rotation)   $\}$   (such Euler angles constrain generated rotation matrices to matrices   with only $-1,0,1$ entries).

and we have chosen representation XYZ for a rotation matrix  (so called [Tait–Bryan case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait-Bryan_angles)) $\,$  i.e.

$R= R_x(\alpha_1)R_y(\alpha_2)R_z(\alpha_3)$

or in the more detailed form

$R= \begin{bmatrix}
 c_2 c_3 & - c_2 s_3 & s_2 \\
 c_1 s_3 + c_3 s_1 s_2 & c_1 c_3 - s_1 s_2 s_3 & - c_2 s_1 \\
 s_1 s_3 - c_1 c_3 s_2 & c_3 s_1 + c_1 s_2 s_3 & c_1 c_2 
\end{bmatrix}$

where $c_j=\cos(\alpha_j)$ and $s_j=\sin(\alpha_j)$.

Theoretically these conditions allow to get $4\times{4}\times{4}= 64$ different Euler representations for rotation matrix, but it is known (for example  from [How many $3 \times 3$ integer matrices are orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038752/how-many-3-times-3-integer-matrices-are-orthogonal/2039498#2039498)) that only $24$ unique rotations are possible, so for sure some Euler representations don't generate unique matrices.

- How to check (without  calculating all possibilities) which of
  the Euler representations of rotation matrix for this kind $i\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ regular rotation generate unique  representation and which don't generate such uniqueness?
- if some are not unique  can we say (also without detailed calculations) how many other representations could  generate the same rotation matrix as with the selected particular Euler representation?

---

Comment: You don't mention any constraints on the numbers in your matrices, unlike the question that you linked to that is constrained to integer matrices. Without such constraints, the answer is that there are uncountably infinitely many rotation matrices: any $3 \times 3$ matrix such that each column (considered as a vector) has dot product with itself equal to 1, and any two distinct columns have dot product with each other equal to zero.

Comment: You could possibly use (finite) group theory: pick three non-identity “generators” $X=R_x(\pi/2), Y=R_y(\pi/2), Z=R_z(\pi/2)$. You could look at their pairwise products (e. g. geometrically, without multiplying any matrices), then use that knowledge for your eulerian products.

Comment: @Leo Mosher I mentioned constraints i.e.   $\alpha_j = \{0,\dfrac{\pi}{2},{\pi}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ (the same effect as in case of $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ rotation)   $\}$ what results necessary in entries of matrix being only $-1,0,1$. Henceforth connection with this other question.

Comment: @arseniiv To say truth I don't see clearly your idea. Maybe it is really hard to devise some clever condition which would discern unique matrices from these which are not unique. I'm staring to believe that the best way would be however to list all $64$ matrices and from their form to try to classify them ( I need such classification for robotic application)..

Comment: Wait...robotics? You have a computer in the loop here? Just compute all 64 and compare. You can do that, effectively instantly, on about \$0.15 of hardware. I don′t see why anyone (including you) should spend more than \$0.15 worth of time trying to think of a more "principled" approach. As a broad point: Euler angles are almost always the wrong answer for robotics, because even when you address the gimbal-lock problem (which is what's hiding beneath here), you haven't solved the far worse "near gimbal lock" problem which is associated with high wear, uncertainty, and uncontrollability. YMMV.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, I know that Euler angles have their drawbacks, however they are still in use.. some robot manufacturers use quaternions for orientation description of a robot tool however some still represent orientation of the frame associated with the effector as Euler angles..

Comment: I meant that, for example, $XY = YZ = ZX$ etc. @JohnHughes is right, anyway.

Comment: @arseniiv Yes, JohnHughes is right, however we have to adapt to existing manipulators.. your idea about finite group is probably very useful but I suspect it needs more details for elaboration...

Comment: ..and through the magic of mathematics, you can *convert* that set of Euler angles to a quaternion (or quaternion pair) in your code (while also seeking out new manufacturers of the assemblies/effectors you're using). The conversion **back** will involve ambiguities...because you're talking about a non-injective function.

Comment: @JohnHughes generally conversion back, I suppose, has to choose from $64$ possibilities having initially $24$ different rotations...