# A certain finite group of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, rotations

There are twenty four $\ \ 3$-dimensional  rotations matrices where entries are from the values $\{-1,0,1\}$,    [see question (*).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038752/how-many-3-times-3-integer-matrices-are-orthogonal/2039498#2039498)
Name  the set of all such matrices $T$ and matrices from this set "orthogonally regular".
They form a finite group as every inverse and product of any two matrices from the set $T$ belongs to this set.

Suppose that we add to the set $T$ a single other rotation matrix which has some entries beyond values $\{ -1,0,1\}$.

- How to  prove that the set generated by all possible matrices from $T$
  and this additional matrix can't be a finite group?
  $ \\ $
  $ \\ $

I'm suspect that the claim is true. Some experimental results support this.

For example suppose that the added to $T$ is the matrix of rotation  about axis $Z$ by $\pi/4$ i.e

$\begin{bmatrix}  \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   & -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\  \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} &  \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

If such matrix belongs to the hypothetical finite group also similar rotations about axes $X$ and $Y$ belong to this group.

For example:

$ \begin{bmatrix}  \  1   & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  \ \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   & -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\ \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  \  1   & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}   \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0  & -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   \\   0 & 1 & 0 \\  \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   \\  \end{bmatrix}$

what is rotation by $(-\pi/4)$ about $Y$.  Inverse also belongs to the group. In similar way we can prove that rotation by $ \pi/4 $ about $X$ also belongs to the group.

But then

$A=\begin{bmatrix}  \ \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   & -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\ \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}& \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   & -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   \\ 0 & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2}   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\dfrac{ 1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}  \\  \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac {1}{2} & -\dfrac{ 1}{2} \\  0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2} } \end{bmatrix} $  should  belong also to this group.

However it seems that a sequence $A,A^2,A^3, ... $ is not cyclic so the group can't be finite. But how to prove a general case ? Is it impossible a finite group which includes all "orthogonally regular" matrices which has more elements than $T$?

Comment: For sequnece $A,A^2,A^3,...$ command {{1/sqrt(2),-1/2,1/2},{1/sqrt(2),1/2,-1/2},{0,1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)}}^2  , etc ...... was used at Wolfram Alpha..

Comment: If it would be easier to prove  orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrices with entries $\{ -1,0,1 \}$ can be considered instead of rotations, there are $48$ such matrices, however my main interest lies in rotations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the diagonal matrices with entries $\pm1$ as a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$, then only half of them are rotations (the ones with determinant $+1$), and form a subgroup $V$ isomorphic to the Klein four group, $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, which is invariant under permuting the diagonal entries. Note that permutations of the diagonal entries are group automorphisms of $V$ (and $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$) and can be achieved by conjugating the diagonal matrix by the appropriate permutation matrix. Moreover, if you multiply such a diagonal matrix by a permutation matrix, you get a "signed permutation matrix" which is a permutation matrix but with possible minus signs. Altogether, this means your group is an internal semidirect product isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2^2\rtimes S_3$.

(Aside: since $S_3=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2^2)$, which by the way is a fun fact to observe, this means your group is the *holomorph* of the Klein four group $\mathrm{Hol}(V)=V\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(V)$. It may also be interpreted as an index $2$ subgroup (or quotient) of the full wreath product $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr S_3=\mathbb{Z}_2^3\rtimes S_3$ which can be achieved as the full group of signed permutation matrices, including those with determinant $-1$.)

[Finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ are classified](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)): they are all cyclic, dihedral, or one of the three permutation groups $A_4,S_4,A_5$, up to isomorphism. (This looks to be an excellent exercise in group actions.) Being nonabelian and of order $24$, the only possibilities are that it is a copy of $S_4$, and in fact $S_4\cong V_4\rtimes S_3$ is a semidirect product. Moreover, checking orders in this classification shows it cannot be a subgroup of a bigger finite group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It clarifies much from abstract algebra point of view. Do you think that other explanation omitting abstract algebra is also possible? Can we somehow show that adding to $T$ group a matrix with non $\pm 1$ entries inevitably leads to the some element $A$ for which sequence $A,A^2,A^3,, $ has infinite number of different elements? (in a fashion similar somehow to this presented in the question?

Comment: @Widawensen Not off the top of my head. But note, you say "in a fashion similar somehow to this presented in this question," but in your question you never said *why* your $A$ generates infinitely many distinct powers, all you say is it "seems" to, so there's really nothing from your question to emulate.

Comment: It visible from the consecutive matrices in the sequence, I calculated them up to $A^8$ what is 1/256(-58 + 47 sqrt(2) | -109 + 64 sqrt(2) | 7 (11 + 18 sqrt(2))
31 (2 + 3 sqrt(2)) | -11 (1 + 10 sqrt(2)) | -109 + 64 sqrt(2)
-2 (-95 + 8 sqrt(2)) | 31 (2 + 3 sqrt(2)) | -58 + 47 sqrt(2)) in the Wolfram Alpha format. Characteristic for this matrix $A$ is coefficient before matrix of the form $1/{2^n}$ ( so it changes as $n$ changes) where $n$ is exponent in $A^n$ and matrix has  always  irrational entries of the form $b+c \sqrt{2}$...

Comment: I asked additional question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574346/rotation-by-n-theta-angle for the problem of $A^n$ and from the answer of Lord Shark the Unknown it seems that really $A^n$ can't be identity..