# Rotation by $n\theta$ angle

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

The   question is linked with [the previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573060/a-certain-finite-group-of-rotations):

I have $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix  $ R=\begin{bmatrix}  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\dfrac{ 1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}  \\  \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac {1}{2} & -\dfrac{ 1}{2} \\  0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2} }  
\end{bmatrix} $

and I would like to be sure that   this matrix can't be a n-th root of Identity for any natural $n$
 i.e. $R^n \neq I$ for any $n$.
The most straightforward method, it seems, is to calculate from the    [trace of $R$  cosine  for rotation angle $ \theta $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix)  of this matrix and to prove that $\cos (n\theta) \neq 1$ for any $n$ (axis remains fixed for $R^n$ operation).

In this case we have $\text{trace}(R)=\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=1+2\cos(\theta)$
and hence $\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}$.

However  [trigonometric identities from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine,_cosine,_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles) seem to be quite difficult to apply and I don't know how to move from this point.

- Is it possible to prove that     if
  $\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}$ then $\cos(n\theta)
     \neq 1$ ?
- Could the proposition be generalized for any expression of the form   $\cos(\theta)=a\sqrt{b}-c$ where $a,c$ are non-zero rational numbers, $b$- natural $>1$ ? if not what are conditions when $\cos(n\theta)=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ then $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}
+e^{-i\theta}$ is an algebraic integer, as $e^{\pm i\theta}$ will be roots of unity.

Here, $2\cos\theta=\sqrt2-1/2$ is not an algebraic integer
(as $\sqrt2$ is an algebraic integer but $1/2$ is not).

Comment: You mean probably 'cos' instead of 'sin'..  what means this construct  'algebraic integer' ? The leaps are too big for me in your answer...

Comment: Now I'm studying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer

Comment: Probably this is a naive question: why we can't multiply additionally sides of equation by two receiving $4\cos\theta=2\sqrt2-1 $ . $2\sqrt2-1$ is "algebraic integer"?

Comment: $2\sqrt2-1$ is an algebraic integer: just as $\sqrt2-1/2$ isn't.

Comment: so why we are using $2\cos\theta$ instead of $4\cos\theta$?, I have feeling that your answer is of course very good but it is so concise that it's hard to grasp its core without previous experience with 'algebraic integers'

Comment: Probably I need more studies to fully understand your answer. I have found for example in https://oeis.org/wiki/Algebraic_integers that $(1+\sqrt{7})/2$ is alg.int. but $(4+\sqrt{7})/2$ not ! (who knows why?)

Comment: @Widawensen $\frac12(1+\sqrt7)$ is not an algebraic integer.

Comment: so it's an error at oeis.org ...

Comment: @Widawensen It is.

Comment: Indeed it's an error. They might have meant $(1+\sqrt{\color{Red}{\bf -}7})/2$ is an algebraic integer.