# Trigonometric expression as an algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, polynomials, rotations

I would like to have more generalized version of    [the answer of Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574346/rotation-by-n-theta-angle/2574378#2574378) for  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574346/rotation-by-n-theta-angle) ..  The concept of algebraic integer is a novelty for me and I'm still uncomfortable with it not knowing what are the exact rules for determining this feature for a given some specific expression (if such rules exist please let me know).

Suppose that we have composition of two 3-d rotations by $\theta$ about $z$ and $x$ axis what gives rotation matrix $R(v,\alpha)$.

$R(v,\alpha)=\begin{bmatrix}  \ \ \cos\theta   & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\theta   & -\sin\theta   \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta   \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}  \cos\theta & -\cos\theta \sin\theta & \sin\theta  \sin\theta\\  \sin\theta& \cos\theta \cos\theta & -\cos\theta \sin\theta\\  0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix} $

(additionally it was assumed that for some $k$ we have cyclicity $\ \ R^k(z,\theta)=R^k(x,\theta)=I$ what means that $\theta$ is a rational times $\pi$)

Matrix $R(v,\alpha)$ is the matrix of rotation  about some axis $v$ by $\alpha$ where   $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are linked by the equation

$\text{tr}(R)=2\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta=1+2\cos\alpha$.

Hence $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{1}{2}(2\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta-1)= \dfrac{1}{2}(2\cos\theta-\sin^2\theta)$.

Now according to Lord Shark  the Unknown's answer in order to determine the cyclicity of $R(v,\alpha)$ we need to check when 
 $ a=2\cos\theta-\sin^2\theta$ is an algebraic integer.

Question ( consider the case  when   $\theta$ is rational times $\pi$ )

- is it true that number $ a=2\cos\theta-\sin^2\theta$ is an algebraic integer
  iff $  \cos\theta $ is an integer (i.e. has values from the set
  $\{-1,0,1\})$?
- how to prove that   the expression $a$ can't be a zero of monic polynomial with integer coefficients beyond this situation ?

Comment: No other restrictions on $\theta$?  The equation $2\cos \theta -\sin^2 \theta =0$ has a root, namely $x≈ - 1.1437 $

Comment: I am not sure I understand your  overall question.  Usually in these problems some assumption is made regarding the algebraic nature of $\theta$.  Absent such an assumption, just take $\theta$ to be the value I gave (presumably it is transcendental).  With that $\theta$ the $\alpha$ you get is $0$, hence obviously an algebraic integer.  You could also get $\alpha =1$.

Comment: More generally, the ring of algebraic integers is dense in $\mathbb R$ so, by continuity, you can get infinitely many algebraic integers of the form you want (unless you restrict $\theta$ in some way).

Comment: I'm asking for what $\theta$ expression $ a=2\cos\theta-\sin^2\theta$ is an algebraic integer..

Comment: I gave you one!  $\theta \approx  - 1.14371774040242\dots$.  With that choice, $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Let me think for a moment about this value...

Comment: Or with $\theta \approx -0.749468865\dots $ you get $\alpha =1$.  Again, with no restrictions on $\theta$ there is no difficulty getting algebraic integers of this form.  Again, in these sort of questions one typically restricts the nature of $\theta$...making it a rational times $\pi$ or something like that.

Comment: I see, you denoted alpha when I denoted "a" so I was disoriented for a moment..

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I haven't got my glasses on.  Looked like an $\alpha$ to me.  Yes, I meant what you called $a$.

Comment: O.k. I could restrict $\theta$ to rational times $\pi$.

Comment: Then I suggest modifying your question to include that restriction.  I suggest also writing $a=2\cos \theta -(1-\cos^2 \theta)=\cos^2(\theta)+2\cos \theta -1=(\cos \theta +1)^2-2$ to see that you are essentially asking for $\cos \theta +1$ to be the square root of an algebraic integer.

Comment: Anyway thank you lulu for your comments, they are very enligthening.. I've even started, it seems to me, to understand better the Lord Shark's answer..

Comment: @lulu I suppose also that a condition can be also expressed taking into account first form of $a$ as asking when $\sin\theta$ is a square root of an algebraic integer as $2\cos\theta$ is a.int. ..

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  $x$ is an algebraic integer iff $(x+1)^2$ is so all you are asking is when $\cos \theta $ is an algebraic integer, given $\theta =\frac ab\pi$.  Now, $\cos \frac ab \pi $ is always algebraic as $e^{\frac ab \pi}$ is a root of unity.  Alas, the real part of that is just half an algebraic integer so I think this is just down to the trivial cases.  I haven't thought that through carefully however.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your remarks, as the whole they could even make  the answer although some details are still missing..

Comment: Yes, there is still a missing step...might not be all that hard though!  Take a shot at it.